# Thumbnail fix in Blueimp Image Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, lazy-loading, blueimp

I have been trying to implement a Image Gallery feature to my project using Blueimp (https://github.com/blueimp/Gallery/blob/master/README.md) but I am facing few problems with the thumbnails being showed in the gallery.

**THE GALLERY**

[image: The actual gallery]

**My problem:**
If I add many images to the gallery, the thumbnails shown increases height of preview div vertically which I dont want.

**My expectation:** I want to give user the ability to scroll through thumbnails with the preview bar having a fixed height

**Trials:** I tried giving overflow:auto and max-height to the  tag and got this result

**WITH OVERFLOW AND MAX-HEIGHT**

[image: The gallery]

**Problem with this:** An ugly scrollbar appears at right of the preview div and moreover scroll happens vertically in this case not horizontally. Also, since I am making a responsive design, I wanted this to be compatible with mobiles too.

Since I will also be emabling Lazy Loading to my Gallery, it would be better if thumbnails and images shown beyond the viewport width load dynamically.

Is there any way I can implement this feature? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I was able to partly implement the feature by using Jquery UI's draggable, setting width as auto, setting all lists to float left, using overflow as hidden and setting a max-height. Now, I am able to drag the preview div in left to view more thumbnails but the problem is if I use the next button, the thumbnail looses focus after last thumbnail visible in viewport (I have to drag to left to see the current thumbnail) 
And I have still not figured about implementing Lazy Loading feature

Comment: you should keep `overflow:hidden` and yea `max-height` seems good but then you should go with custom left and right navigation!! Or how is your idea of displaying extra thumbnails??

Comment: I am using left and right navigation already and I am using overflow:hidden now (See edit) but new problems keep arising.. My idea of displaying extra thumbnails is that users can drag the thumbnails to see the rest which I have implemented now. (Though I have problems as mentioned in edit)

Comment: It would be great if we get to see a small demo rather than theory here as this is the problem of `CSS`